# Roblox - creating a multistory maze

Tags: roblox, maze, multi-level

I am trying to create a multistory maze.  I found it fairly easy to create the first level, then I realized I had no idea how to simply raise this first level up in order to create a second level beneath it.

Also, is there a way to 'fuse' all of these wall parts into one object and then raise this object up?

Edit:  Much to my embarrassment, their is a way to fuse objects.  The 'Union' tool is what I needed, but had no idea existed.  I 'fused' (unioned) the various parts that made up my walls and joined them together into one big part.  After that unioning, moving the entire maze upwards became quite easy.

Comment: Kurt Isley, could you provide a little more information? Are you using a maze generator to create each level, or are you building everything by hand? Have you tried parenting all of the walls in a Group object? That would allow you to move them all at the same time if you've Anchored or Welded each piece.

Comment: Hi Kylaa,  Yes I am creating this by hand.  Putting them in a Group Object sounds like what I am trying to do, but I didn't not see a way to do it from within Roblox Studio.  My Roblox Programming book arrives today, so now I know what to look for when I get the book.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem but I think that you're making a 3D maze in roblox and you want the first level to go up and the second level to form below the level.

If the maze is NOT procedurally generated AND the maps are built by hand. Then you can make the script detect if the player won, and then raise the first level by either using tween or using loops (I'd recommend tween because loops and linear tweening does the same), and then make an effect that shows it forming (Transparency, parts coming back together, etc..).

I will show you the simplest example. But you can add whatever you want

```
local ts = game:GetService("TweenService")
local ti = TweenInfo.new(0.5, Enum.TweenStyle.Linear, Enum.TweenDirection.Out) --Customize it to your liking
local levels = game.LevelStorageParent.LevelFolderOrModelHere:GetChildren()
local pos = workspace.Level1.Position --Change (Not the levels because we are not cloning this)
local levelYRaise = 10 --Put any number or just get bounding box for full raise

ts:Create(workspace.Level1, ti, {Position = Vector3.new(pos.X, pos.Y+levelYRaise, pos.Z):Play()

local newLevel = levels.Level2:Clone()
newLevel.Parent = workspace
newLevel.Pos = workspace.Level1.Position - Vector3.new(0, workspace.Level1.Size.Y, 0)
newLevel.Transparency = 1

ts:Create(newLevel, ti, {Transparency = 0}):Play()
```

Change the code to your liking and your hierarchy names and parenting

Comment: I believe you understand what I am trying to do.  I started with a 'Classic Baseplate'.  I added 'block' part and made it very long and narrow (1,15,30) and used it as a building block for my walls.  I then duplicated this elemental part many times and placed them together to form the walls of my maze.  My intention is for the player to start on the top floor and for them to work their way down, so I created the top floor first.  It was only after I created this top floor that I realized that I couldn't think of a way to raise this floor up and create then next level beneath it.

Comment: Ok is there any problems that you have with my answer?

Comment: Nope.  It's a good answer and I appreciate your help.